# Updated to 21.10 -- desktop still says 21.04

Tags: upgrade, 21.04, 21.10

I just updated my Ubuntu 21.04 (running on Raspberry Pi 4) to 21.10.  `lsb_release -a` shows 21.10 on the command line but the GUI desktop still says 21.04 in the bottom left corner.

[image: image of desktop at boot]

What should I do?

Comment: Providing a picture may have helped us understand, but if you're talking about a wallpaper; those aren't changed because users may like their selected wallpaper, but you can change it yourself.  You've tagged server, where server installs don't have a GUI desktop so picture may help us understand.

Comment: The unity-greeter I use displays the version dynamically there. This looks like that greeter.

Comment: Have you restarted the computer?

Comment: The system automatically restarted after the update process.  That is why I was curious about the screen.  However, upon restarting gdm services today (after a screen freeze after logging in), I got the usual Ubuntu screen with no version # on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already told by [Vanadium](https://askubuntu.com/users/558158/vanadium), you can change the wallpaper to wallpaper of Ubuntu 21.10.

You can change the wallpaper by:

First, install the lightdm greeter settings:

```
sudo apt install lightdm-gtk-greeter && sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings
```

Now set the lightdm login screen to lightdm-greeter:

```
echo [SeatDefaults] > /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
echo greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Open the lightdm greeter settings app:

```
sudo lightdm-greeter-settings
```

[image: lightdm]
*old screenshot*

From there, you can easily change the image by clicking on the image option.

Example image:

[image: Ubuntu 21.10]

Comment: The unity-greeter I use displays the version dynamically there. This looks like that greeter.

Comment: @OrganicMarble How did you upgrade to 21.10? By default, lightdm uses Unity greeter. IMO unity greeter is not that configurable. So lightdm greeter! It is much better!

Comment: I did not upgrade to 21.10. I use 20.04.

Comment: Thank you for info.  After restarting gdm service today, got the usual default Ubuntu login screen (with no version #).  No idea what happened (I know I've rebooted a couple or more times), but this screen works for me.